# How to derserialize complex object using JsonConvert?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I want to deserialize a `jsonData`

JSON:

```
{
  "$id":"1",
  "Success":true,
  "Message":[],
  "Data: [
    {
      "$id":"2",
      "ID":1,
      "StudentCount":"30",
      "Boys":"15",
      "Girls":"15",
      "EntryDate":"2013-06-12T00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I have written to deserialize. I am not getting any error
but showing the same data as JSON.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string json = wc.DownloadString("http://localhost:43293/api/Common");
var oc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Outcome>(json);
```

Class:

```
public class Outcome
{
     public bool Success { get; set; }
     public List<string> Message { get; set; }
     public object Data { get; set; }
     public Outcome()
     {
        Message = new List<string>();
     }
}
```

I am not able to deserialize the object: `public object Data { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your Json-object `Data` cannot be deserialized to an instance of the C#-type `object`, since you are not giving a concrete class that provides properties for `$id, ID, StudentCount, ...`

Try to introduce a concrete class for your property `Data` or deserialize into a dynamic object:

```
dynamic oc = JsonConvert.Deserialize(json);
```